# Gear icon in reputation block is not placed in the correct place

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

In the [Activity tab - REPUTATION](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) section, the "Track my next privilege" gear icon is placed near the "Next tag badge".

Previously it was placed over the tag score progress bar. Can this be placed as per the old screen?

Current screen:

> [image: Current screen]

Old screen:

> [image: Old screen]